# Prolog Assigning integer to a variable

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog, and using GNU Prolog, so no clp(fd) allowed. What I'm trying to do is for a given integer N, generate a list with elements of 1 ~ N. So set(3,T). will output T = [1,2,3].
Here is what I have so far:

```
set(0,[]).
set(N,T):-set(N-1,T1),append(T1,[N],T).
```

When I try set(2,T), it crashes. I debugged with trace, and find out that it's not evaluating N-1, but rather doing N-1-1-1...

Anyone can tell me how to solve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
set(N,T):- N2 is N-1, set(N2,T1), append(T1,[N],T).
```

Arithmetic operations are performed by using `is/2`. `N-1` is a shorthand for `-(N,1)` (just like `N2 is N-1` is shorthand for `is(N2, N-1)`), so you were just creating infinite tree `-(-(-(-(...),1),1,1,1)`.

**Little educational note:**

If you want `set/2` to be proper relation so it can answer queries like `set(3,X)`, `set(X, [1,2,3])` and `set(X,Y)` without error then you should write this predicate that way:

```
set(0, []).
set(Value, List) :-
  length(List, Value),
  append(ShorterList, [Value], List),
  ValueMinusOne is Value - 1,
  set(ValueMinusOne, ShorterList).
```

That way result of arithmetic operation is always possible to obtain because input value (lenght of the list) is either explicitly given or generated from `length/1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
n_ups(N, Xs) :-
   length(Xs, N),
   numbered_from(Xs, 1).

numbered_from([], _).
numbered_from([I0|Is], I0) :-
   I1 is I0+1,
   numbered_from(Is, I1).
```

In fact, the complexity is hidden within `length/2`.