# How to make a list of integers from 1 to N

Tags: prolog

I'm using GNU Prolog, and was told that this can be solved with Finite Domain Solver, or just `member/2` and `is/2`. I can only come up with using both together, but it's not working. Here is what I have so far:

```
unique([],N,0).
unique([H|T],N,N1) :-
    length([H|T],N1),
    N2 is N1-1,
    unique(T,N,N2),
    H #> 0,
    H #=< N.
    \+ member(H,T).
```

When I debug `unique(X,3,3)` with `trace`, I can see that when it calls `member/2`, it's comparing 2 domains, `1..3` and `1..3` and succeed, which it shouldn't. Anyone can help?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261379/prolog-assigning-integer-to-a-variable/23276168#23276168

Comment: I want X to be any permutation of [1,2,3].

Comment: Note that there should be a comma instead of the dot before `\+ member`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this solution doesn't use FD or `member/2`. ;)

Using a [prior solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261379/prolog-assigning-integer-to-a-variable) to the problem of generating the list of integers from 1 to N:

```
n_ups(N, Xs) :-
   length(Xs, N),
   numbered_from(Xs, 1).

numbered_from([], _).
numbered_from([I0|Is], I0) :-
   I1 is I0+1,
   numbered_from(Is, I1).
```

You can then use the GNU built-in permutation predicate:

```
unique(N, P) :-
    n_ups(N, L),
    permutation(L, P).
```

Results for `unique(3, L)`:

```
| ?- unique(3, L).

L = [1,2,3] ? a

L = [1,3,2]

L = [2,1,3]

L = [2,3,1]

L = [3,1,2]

L = [3,2,1]

no
| ?-
```

If you want to roll your own permutation, then:

```
perm([], []).
perm(List, [H|Perm]) :-
    select(H, List, Rest),
    perm(Rest, Perm).
```

Comment: Why don't you put the simple case first in perm/2?

Comment: @false I had no good reason. I just thought of it in that order and wrote it that way. Good catch.